# Field view in content type or header custom field

Tags: views

I have a need, it is to create a page with a list of contents but also custom fields in introduction, such as a title, text and an image to display on the page. I am exploring several solutions but I face a problem each time, I need all the data apart from the view to be contributed in the same place for simplicity.

Via the view I tried to add a content block in the header, but it must be added in block layout and I do not want to overload this part (unless I am wrong on this point there). Otherwise above I don't see how to add fields in the 'header' part of the view which could be modifiable directly via the view (as for the content types ultimately)

Another approach, I told myself that I could create a "List" content type where I put the fields I need and I create a field where I refer to the view, it only works for the configuration of the view. the view and not the rendering?
Otherwise isn't there a way to link a view to a content type or at least restrict the display in a custom field of a content type?

I may not be going about it the right way, but if you have good practices or other advice on how to approach this need, I'm interested!

THANKS !